# What is the best practice to connect an incoming web socket to Kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to message queues in general and at the moment I'm working with apache Kafka. I have a python script that takes data from a crypto currency exchange and sends it to one of the Kafka topics. Are there better ways of connecting web sockets to Kafka as producers other than using scripting?

Comment: Define "better". For example, if you could write a Kafka Connector to pull that data instead, it would be scalable and not require moving python code around to multiple computers

Comment: Better as in not managing extra python code but some sort of plugin for kafka . I'll look into how to create kafka connectors. Thanks

Comment: The Apache section on Connect isn't that great. Start here, or go look at the Confluent Hub to see if one of the connects already does what you want. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html